# cannot create link operation not permitted

Tags: linux

I am getting error "link cannot create link operation not permitted" while creating link in ubuntu using below command

```
link code-1.2.1 code
```

I am using ubuntu 12.10 version also i tried it using 'sudo link code-1.2.1 code' command but still getting same error.

Thanks.

Comment: sudo link code-1.2.1 code

Comment: Why is the question tagged `php`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are attempting to create a hardlink to a directory. Linux will not allow this. Create a symlink instead (`ln -s`).